# Attaching an entity of type 'SistemaIndustrial.Domain.Entities.Pessoa'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm make update in my table, but the current table should be saved in other table, on pessoaAntiga I  save the Pessoa but at the time it executes the Entity return an error.

```
 public ActionResult Edit(PessoaViewModel pessoa)
    {
        var pessoaAntiga = _pessoaApp.GetById(pessoa.PessoaId);

        _pessoaApp.Update(Mapper.Map<PessoaViewModel, Pessoa>(pessoa));
        var lista = new List<HistoricoDeAlteraCliFor>();
```

> Attaching an entity of type 'SistemaIndustrial.Domain.Entities.Pessoa' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Comment: Please clarify your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF is just telling your that he can't attach this entity because this entity already have a type with this primary key.

This is because your are not updating the correct object.

You need to map `pessoa`changes to `pessoaAntiga`.

Have a look to this link to know more about EF update

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/update-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx